# ORA-12505: Listener refused the connection with the following error -- SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

In the past i got no problem doing this, but when i've reinstalled Oracle 11g and SQL Developer, i got in troubles. I am trying to connect my oracle 11g database to sql developer, but when I test the connection, I get this error. I tried everything: config file, tnsnames.ora changed several times, listener.ora file changed, but it was all in vain. I have seen many videos or posts dealing with the error, and they all say to look at the match between the SID and the Host name/Service name in the tnsnames.ora file, but in my case they are correct and coincide. Can anyone help me out? I've deleted everything: files, env variables etc.

[image: The error]

When i open SQL Developer, it automatically detects the tns file, so it is actually read, so I don't understand what the problem could be.

[image: SQL Developer detects the tns file]

This is my tnsnames.ora

```
    XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-SMTRG338)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

This is the listener

```
   SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-SMTRG338)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic connection does not make use of the tnsnames.ora file.

Basic is EZConnect: `user/pass@host:port/SERVICE_NAME`

You can try to check `"Nombre servizio"` and set it to `XE` and connect, but I do not think it will solve your problem.

For scenarios like this, the `alert_<SID>.log` is your friend. Here you can diagnose the database health.

Your Windows Service can be `running`, but your database can be in any of these modes: `shutdown | nomount | mount | open`

```
%ORACLE_BASE%\diag\rdbms\xe\XE\trace\alert_XE.log
```

Note! Please do not use `notepad.exe` reading log-files. In Windows-land `Notepad++` is a better option.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I've checked that log file, but there are more than 1k rows, and i don't even know what to look for inside it. I've also checked files like listener.log or sqlnet.log. Inside sqlnet.log i got "Directory does not exist for read/write [C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\log] [C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\log\diag]" and in listener.log i got "23-NOV-2021 17:50:40 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xe)(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=Gigi))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=58727)) * establish * xe * 12505

Comment: Stop the Windows Oracle XE Service, delete the log, and start the service again. It will tell you if the database reaches open state or if there is something else going on.

Comment: I get always the same errors. I've even installed the db inside a new disk partition, but that was useless

Comment: After creating the clients folder inside "app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\log\diag\", i've noticed a change in sqlnet.log, which gives me this error "Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=oracle)(ARGV0=oracleXE)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))')))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=I:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\oradim.exe)(HOST=LAPTOP-SMTRG338)(USER=Gigi))))"